# Using ARC does NSMutableArray needs property?

Tags: objective-c

I have switched my project to ARC with Xcode. he did remove the `release` commands, but the array i already had - does not have a `property`- and Xcode didn't add it to them after the conversion .

Do i have to set `property` to `NSMutableArray` or not ?

```
.h
NSMutableArray *array; 

.m
array= [[NSMutableArray alloc] init ];
```

**Reason i am trying to avoid it**, is that its so annoying ,to add it and than adding synchronize to it ,it seems so old .  i just want to set and array , and go on . not too much messing with it. i think most people don't need that complexity anyway, they only need a simple array , without thinking if its strong, weak, to synchronize it , etc .

Answer (score 2):

The ivars are strong by default, then you are not forced to add property. But property are very useful and i advise you to use them often.

You can use property and you are not also forced to add synthesize. You can just do like this :
in .h

```
@property (nooatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *array;
```

And the compiler will generates the getter and setter for you without the synthesize.

In the .m, use direct access for your ivar in the init ( or custom init if there is one) and uses property in somewhere else.

in .m for example :

```
- (id)init{
    self = [super init];
    if(self){
      _array = ...
    }
    return self;
}
```

somewhere else in your .m use the setter and getter directly like this :

```
- (void)myMethod{
        self.array = ...
     }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot , but i don't see even one advantage to use it, its just more lines of code , and it gives me nothing (getter and setter are not relevant here since NSArrays have their own functions to use them , so whats the point of it ?

Comment: @Curnelious: It's one line of code for an instance variable and one line of code for a property. And all objects "have their own functions to use them." A property gives you better encapsulation at very little cost.

Answer (score 1):

If I did understand your question correctly - there is not really any problem. Just leave it as it is. The reference from an iVar is strong. Therefore your array will remain until you set `array=nil` (and of course do not hold any other stron reference).

However, to keep things simple plus using the advantages of the OO concept, I tend to create the iVars as properties in a second interface section within the .m file. Hoever, that may be down to personal style. Simple iVars have advantages too. So stick to them when you are comfortable with them.

In this very situation, where you migrate legady code to ARC, there is no really good reason for converting iVars to properties (or adding property declarations to existing iVars).

Comment: Why would i want to use a property in that case anyway? its more lines of code, do i really need that ??

Comment: That depends on what you focus on. A property is overwritable, an iVar is not. (afaik) However, its overwriteability does not come for free. All getters and setters have to be bound on runtime which is less performant than accesing an iVar (which is just a member of a struct in the end). As I said, if you don't want one then you do not need one.

Answer (score 0):

Instance variables are declared in a class in which each instance of that class gets its own copy of the instance variables declared by the class.

Also you don't need to convert all your instance variables to properties.

A property is really just a promise that a class provides certain accessors with certain semantics. Just having an instance variable doesn't mean that you have to provide accessors for that ivar.

Please for below link for more detail example:-

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011226-CH1-SW16